# How to measure a steady state load and surge load of relay?

Tags: relay

I am asked to test a relay and show that it is capable of handling steady state load of 0.2 A at 27.5 Vdc and 2.0 A surge load with a maximum of 10 ms at 27.5 Vdc.

How can I do this test and measurements?
The relay that used in the circuit as follow:
[image]

Comment: What about breaking current? If you are only concerned about steady state, apply 0.2 A and measure the temperature rise, then supply a 2 A pulse for 10 ms?

Comment: Can you advise WHY you have been asked to do this? As has been pinted out, the relay datasheet shows it is specified for more stringent conditions that you are testing for. Were you arae of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am asked to test a relay* \$\color{red}{\text{and show}}\$ *that it is capable of handling
> steady state load of 0.2 A at 27.5 Vdc and 2.0 A surge load with a
> maximum of 10 ms at 27.5 Vdc.*

My answer demonstrates that you don't need to test anything to **show** that it is capable of meeting the stated requirement. Here's an image of relay K2 captured from question: -

[image]

[Fujitsu FTR 12 volt coil relay data sheet link](https://docs.rs-online.com/f0ba/0900766b813f3688.pdf).

Firstly, there is nothing I can think of that might be gained in testing a relay beyond the limits stated in its data sheet. The data sheet limits will be supported by Fujitsu's quality department and, it will have undergone extensive testing until the device reaches the end of its life. In short, it will likely be tested to a higher standard than that which you or I could test to: -

[image]

Secondly, if the testing you wish to do is **within the limits** set out in the data sheet, is there any justifiable reason to do any testing yourself?

Comment: This test is far under your example rated  current.  It's an academic question of how to design a load and measure switch losses I^2R possibly in burning contacts, but it's always good to teach how to read datasheets

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Your comment is somewhat obscure (to old brains anyway). I think that you are agreeing both with what Andy said (OP test is inside data seet limits) AND that you are complimenting Andy on his advice on using datasheets. It may be useful to clarify.

Comment: it's not obscure to me. The question "

I am asked to test a relay" is different from the answered response.  it is a valid request. Reading datasheets are good but irrelevant since they're unknown.

Comment: In fact, his answer completely ignores the question of how to test a relay. (-1)  . How to measure arc voltages and contact power losses and contact bounce is more difficult, so the OP only needs to measure current AC and DC. Mentioning the datasheet deserves an "ATTABOY" describing how to interpret the results might be +1

Comment: The question is this: *I am asked to test a relay and* **show** *that it is capable of handling steady state load of 0.2 A at 27.5 Vdc and 2.0 A surge load with a maximum of 10 ms at 27.5 Vdc.* and, my answer clearly states that you don't need to test anything to **show** that it is capable of the stated requirement.

Comment: @Andyaka , I thinks that the test i want to do is not beyond the limits in the datasheet. The reason is that i am working on  electrical design which should be compliant with a specific starndard requierements. One of these requierements says that in the design i have to work with "relay capable of handling steady state load of 0.2 A at 27.5 Vdc and 2.0 A surge load with a maximum of 10 ms at 27.5 Vdc." So i am looking for a testing method to show that my circuit complies with this condition.

Comment: @Andyaka, Otherwise , if you say that there is no reason to do this test, How can i validate my circuit and make sure that the relay works and switches correctly. Please note that this is the first time i test a circuit with a relay, that's why i am asking this kind of questions.

Comment: @Y.OU the relay data sheet validates your requirements and, the fact that the relay is made by a reputable supplier with a recognized quality system is all on the plus side for this being a paper/written exercise. To make sure your circuit works you test it as you would test any other circuit that you might build but, that test does not need to pay special attention to ensuring that the load can be switched because the data sheet does that for you.

Comment: In other words, if your relay control circuit can activate and deactivate the relay (and it looks like it should from your diagram) then you should choose a nominal load and a nominal supply voltage for that load and check that your prototype/working model does what you expect it to. In other words you are performing a **functional check** rather than a performance check on the relay's switching capabilities @Y.OU

Answer (score 2):

> I am asked to test a relay and show that it is capable of handling steady state load of 0.2 A at 27.5 Vdc and 2.0 A surge load with a maximum of 10 ms at 27.5 Vdc.

Normally this is done by looking up the specs of the relay. Testing it would require proper lab setup - you'd be essentially replicating the testing done on relay samples by the product development department of any competent relay manufacturer. They typically have their custom test setups to do this, able to provide well-controlled loads to the contacts, detect arcing, dynamic contact resistance during both contact closure and opening, varying the operating temperature, applying vibrations to determine the operating and storage/handling vibratory envelope, etc.

It's not something you can do in an afternoon or two. You can quickly exclude an entirely unsuitable relay that way perhaps, but showing that it'll actually perform well in your application is a significant endeavor if you truly know nothing about the relay, i.e. have no specs and are treating it as a black box.

If you don't have specs available but insist on using the relay - hey, maybe you got a million of them for US$0.01 each and figure it may have been a jackpot - you'll need to submit the relay to a lab to do some reverse-engineering on it, determine the materials it's built with and the design used, perform life/load testing, and give you a report. Some relay manufacturers' R&D labs may be willing to do this for you for a fee.

Comment: My purpose is not to test the relay independently, but to test it in my circuit and make sure that it switches and works correctly.

Answer (score -1):

1. How do you make a 2A surge load of 10 ms @ 27.5V/0.2Adc
2. How do you verify it and that the contact resistance meets spec thus does not over heat too long. (Measure V/I=R)

1. A capacitor  RC load can be made with a series R and shunt C, then a discharge R across C for repeating tests.  R= V/I  and using t=1T pprox. depending on criteria for surge choose C.  R1 for 2A is in series with Cap and R2 is shunt for 0.2A, Cap can be 640 uF  for Rs = 14 Ohms = 28V/2A and Rp=140 Ohms for 0.2A but 10 Watts using multiple resistors. A fancy way is to use a 50W PNP used at 6W with a small heat since and bias the base for an equivalent 140 Ohms across Vce. (Active load)

2. To measure current easily a series 100mV shunt resistor ( for surge tests and 50 mV for DC TESTS) between Ground and the contact that was to ground. Keep 10:1 probe ground lead very short and use 20 MHz filter on DSO. Thus Rs= 0.5 ohm for 200 mA and 100 mV will not interfere with load test using 14 Ohm resistor and series C= 700 uF such that RC = 10ms. Consider a tolerance on C= 20%.

Relays rated for <2A are gold plated for non-oxidizing low voltages such as Telephony. Beware of inductance and use twisted pairs for switched currents to partially cancel the supply and return inductance.

Plan B is to use a 50 Hz low voltage source that can supply 2A and full wave rectify into 700 uF with Rs = 14 Ohms then measure peak rectified sine current as Caps charge up for 1st cycle and 2nd cycle.

Comment: In general the surge current for conducting a capacitive load might have the same harmful effect as breaking an inductive load with a clamp diode.  The surge current in the breakdown voltage events are similar. Thus switching ON a surge of 2A say to charge an ACDC capacitor with current limiting Rs elevates the contacts from the > 5000'K arc temperatures that might only last some number of microseconds.. Similarily when contacts start to break open in um gaps the breakdown is only 3 mV/um then ionization times ~ >1us certainly arcs before the voltage reaches the diode clamp voltage.